# Where do the 'discarded' stickers go?

Tags: stick-it-to-the-man

In *Stick it to the Man!*, say you pick a sticker. Then, without using it, you pick another.

Is there an inventory? Where does the sticker go?

Answer (score 2):

It is unfortunate that the game has no interface for listing and changing controls after launch

Some kind steam users listed some controls for us:

- PAGE UP and PAGE DOWN to alternate stickers (the answer to my original question)
- M for map (to exit, either ESC or M twice, you might get locked in the map some times)
- T for music (not sure what this means, presumably mutes the music)
- While reading minds: A to reverse, D to fast-forward

These are the defaults, there is a screen to change keyboard bindings before running the game proper (but no in-game screen)

Original thread: https://steamcommunity.com/app/251830/discussions/0/648817378065673989/ (all commands up to 19 feb 2024 where copied to this post)